# How do I cycle console output text in a java application?

Tags: java, user-interface, console

I'm making a simple cracking application. Part of the application runs through a dictionary.txt and try the words in there. It will return 1 if a simple dictionary word is returned. (For the purpose of the assignment we're not worrying about capitals.) This is the snippet where it runs through the dictionary attack:

```
for(String s : rf.openFile()){
            System.out.println("Testing: " + s)
            if(password.equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

rf.openFile() is a String[] containing the dictionary after loading the txt.

Now, I'd like to know this: obviously the println() there is going to output a bajillion lines to the console. I don't know how to word it (it's something a lot of applications do while they check through filesystems), but I'd like to make it so the line reads "Testing: [word]" And the word changes while keeping "Testing:" static as it iterates through Strings. How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that through the console. Well, not without using charva, which is an ncurses wrapper for java. You don't have control of the console itself with java. You can only write to it and read from it. What you're trying to accomplish is essentially writing the word to the console, clearing the console, and writing the next word.

I suppose you could just write X number of empty lines to the console after the text, to give it the appearance you want, but scrolling back up would reveal many blank lines.

I'd say the easiest way to do this would be to have a simple JFrame with a JLabel:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    final JLabel label = new JLabel();
    frame.add(label);
    frame.setSize(100, 30);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    checkDictionary(label);
}

public static int checkDictionary(final JLabel label) {
    for (final String s : rf.openFile()) {
        label.setText("Testing: [" + s + "]");
        if (password.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```